# A sealed resource is missing or invalid

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, code-signing

I'm trying to deploy my game made with Unity on Mac Store, but got this error during the validation process. I don't know how to correct. Do you have any ideas please ?

> Invalid Signature - The main app bundle Kissoro at path Kissoro.app
>   has following signing error(s):
>   --prepared:/Volumes/data01/app_data/dstr/mz_8224354388357841556dir/mz_8662652241696651587dir/com.masseka.game.studio.Kissoro.pkg/Payload/Kissoro.app/Contents/Frameworks/libcrypto.dylib
>   --validated:/Volumes/data01/app_data/dstr/mz_8224354388357841556dir/mz_8662652241696651587dir/com.masseka.game.studio.Kissoro.pkg/Payload/Kissoro.app/Contents/Frameworks/libcrypto.dylib
>   --prepared:/Volumes/data01/app_data/dstr/mz_8224354388357841556dir/mz_8662652241696651587dir/com.masseka.game.studio.Kissoro.pkg/Payload/Kissoro.app/Contents/Frameworks/libssl.dylib
>   --validated:/Volumes/data01/app_data/dstr/mz_8224354388357841556dir/mz_8662652241696651587dir/com.masseka.game.studio.Kissoro.pkg/Payload/Kissoro.app/Contents/Frameworks/libssl.dylib
>   --prepared:/Volumes/data01/app_data/dstr/mz_8224354388357841556dir/mz_8662652241696651587dir/com.masseka.game.studio.Kissoro.pkg/Payload/Kissoro.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libmono.0.dylib
>   --validated:/Volumes/data01/app_data/dstr/mz_8224354388357841556dir/mz_8662652241696651587dir/com.masseka.game.studio.Kissoro.pkg/Payload/Kissoro.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libmono.0.dylib
>   --prepared:/Volumes/data01/app_data/dstr/mz_8224354388357841556dir/mz_8662652241696651587dir/com.masseka.game.studio.Kissoro.pkg/Payload/Kissoro.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libMonoPosixHelper.dylib
>   --validated:/Volumes/data01/app_data/dstr/mz_8224354388357841556dir/mz_8662652241696651587dir/com.masseka.game.studio.Kissoro.pkg/Payload/Kissoro.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libMonoPosixHelper.dylib
>   /Volumes/data01/app_data/dstr/mz_8224354388357841556dir/mz_8662652241696651587dir/com.masseka.game.studio.Kissoro.pkg/Payload/Kissoro.app:
>   a sealed resource is missing or invalid . Refer to the Code Signing
>   and Application Sandboxing Guide at
>   http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/AboutCS/AboutCS.html
>   and Technical Note 2206 at
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html
>   for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to manually codesign every file in Contents/Frameworks and Contents/Plugins directories inside .app file and to delete all .meta files inside your plugin. After U do these steps, You codesigned once more the whole .app file and create a package which You can uploaded on iTunes Connect without warning mentioned above.
More info: https://forum.unity.com/threads/signing-mac-app-on-os-x-mavericks.206762/

Comment: I codesign all files I have in Contents/Frameworks. I have 4 frameworks. And in my plugins folder, I don't have meta files.